# How to dynamically Redirect in react router dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a custom hook which returns true if the user is logged in else will return false.

**useAuth.js**

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

```
const useAuth = () => {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsAuth(localStorage.getItem("auth"));
  }, []);

  if (!!isAuth) {
    console.log("Auth", isAuth);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

export default useAuth;
```

I want to dynamically redirect users to /dashboard if logged in or /login if not logged in.

**Login.jsx**

```
const Login = () => {
  function onLogin() {
    localStorage.setItem("auth", "token");
  }
  return <button onClick={onLogin}>Login</button>;
};

export default Login;
```

**Dashboard.jsx**

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  return <h1>Dashboard</h1>;
};

export default Dashboard;
```

I have a separate file for handling routing

**Router.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from "./useAuth";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Login from "./Login";

const Router = () => {
  const isAuth = useAuth();

  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/login",
      component: Login,
    },
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      component: Dashboard,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route) => {
            return (
              <Route
                key={route.path}
                exact
                path={route.path}
                component={route.component}
              />
            );
          })}
          <Redirect to={isAuth ? "/dashboard" : "/login"} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

But it's always getting redirected to "/login". Any way to solve this?

Codesandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-joliot-h89gq?file=/src/Router.js

Comment: Hi Abi, the `<Switch />` component will render the first matching child, so if you already are on either `/login` or `/dashboard` you will never be redirected anywhere. If you navigate to a route like `/xyz` you will however be redirect depending on your auth status.

Comment: `this.props.history.push('/login');`

Comment: @AmirSaleem cannot read property props of undefined

Comment: @JackGore What I wanted to do is, redirect to /login if not authenticated and to /dashboard if authenticated

Comment: @Abi you need to export your component with `withRouter(MyComponent)`. You can import with router from `react-router-dom`

Comment: @AmirSaleem any reference on that?

Answer (score 1):

@Abi Place redirect statement outside of switch statement, it will work. for more info, see this issue on github- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6840.